# How to map multiple services to a single ingress using AWS ALB as Ingress Controller?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a single ingress (example, [www.a.com](http://www.a.com)). I have mapped the root to a service, like so:

```
- backend:
    serviceName: ui-svc
    servicePort: 80
  path: /
```

This routes to the correct service when  go to [www.a.com](http://www.a.com). I want to mount another service on /api, like so:

```
- backend:
    serviceName: api-svc
    servicePort: 80
  path: /api
```

The routing to [www.a.com/api](http://www.a.com/api) works fine, however any trailing endpoints get 404'd (etc [www.a.com/api/swagger](http://www.a.com/api/swagger), even though this endpoint is mounted in the application itself (spring application)). Previously, using Traefik, I've used the `rewriteTarget: /` annotation to remedy this, however ALB does not support this. Is there a kubernetes native way that I can solve this problem?

I am using kubernetes 1.17 and EKS as my kubernetes platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to match the path

```
- backend:
    serviceName: api-svc
    servicePort: 80
  path: /api/.*
```

This can be enabled by setting this annotation in your ingress deployment:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
```

more info https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using nginx as the ingress (using alb), so that rule isnt available.

Comment: You still can use the `*` in the path, right? https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/guide/ingress/spec/

Answer (score 0):

This has since been remedied by adding

`server.servlet.context-path=/*relvantPathName*`

As an environment variable to the containers. This is a spring specific thing, where it needs to rewrite the root in order to work.